# Compute the Characteristics of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Let $\displaystyle u_x^2+u_y^2=n_0^2$ be given, with the initial condition that $u(x,2x)=1$ and $n_0\in\mathbb{R}$

I want to find a solution using the methods of characteristics. I computed the characteristics to be

$\displaystyle
\begin{align}
\dot{\vec p}&=0\\
\dot z(s)=2\left |\vec p\right |^2&=n_0\\
\dot{\vec x}&=2\vec p\end{align}$

Leading to

$\displaystyle\begin{align}
p_1 &= c_1\\
p_2&=c_2\\
x_1&=2c_1s\\
x_2&=2c_2s\\
z&=n_0s+c_3\end{align}$

My problem is that I can not go on from here. I need an expression for $u$ before I can use the BC, but this means solving the equations.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(+dz%2Fdx+)%5E2+%2B+(+dz%2Fdy+)%5E2+%3D+A%5E2+for+z(x,y)) computation may be useful

Comment: Answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577539/solving-u-x2u-y2-n-02-using-method-of-characteristics?rq=1.